# Speeding Up Query Calls to MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am parsing an XML file consisting of ~600K lines. Parsing and Inserting the data from the XML to the database is not a problem as I am using SAX to parse and using LOAD DATA INFILE (from a .txt file) to INSERT into the database. The txt file is populated in Java using JDBC. All of this takes a good 5 seconds to populate in the database.

My bottle neck is now executing multiple SELECT queries. Basically, each time I hit a certain XML tag, I would call the SELECT query to grab a data from another DB table. Adding these SELECT queries brings my populating time to 2 minutes.

For example:

1. I am parsing through an XML consisting of books, articles, thesis, etc.
2. Each book/article has child elements such as isbn, title, author, editor, publisher.
3. At each author/editor/publisher, I need to query a table in a database.
4. Let's say I encountered the author tag with value Tolkien.
5. I need to query a table that already exist in the database called author_table
6. The query is [select author_id from author_table where name = 'Tolkien']

This is where the bottle neck is happening.

Now my question is: Is there a way to speed this up?

BTW, the reason why I think 2 minutes is long is because this is a homework assignment and I am not yet finished with populating the database. I would estimate that the whole DB population would take 5 minutes. Thus the reason why I am seeking advice for performance optimization.

Comment: Quetion is not clear. You should explain more about bottle neck.

Comment: I apologize for that. I updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things you can consider:

- Use [connection pooling](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjj.html) so you don't create/close a new connection everytime you're executing query. Doing so is expensive
- Cache whatever data you are obtaining via SELECT query. Is it possible to prefetch all the data beforehand so you don't have to query them on the spot?
- If your SELECT is slow, ensure the query is optimized and you have appropriate index in place to avoid scanning the whole table
- Ensure you [use buffered IO in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html)
- Can you subdivide the work into multiple threads? If so create multiple worker thread to do multiple instance of your job in parallel

Comment: I learned about connection pooling earlier in the course. Definitely will try that one out.

When you said caching, what method do you recommend? Did you mean putting the prefetch data into a data structure like a hashset and then search through the hashset?

Comment: Hey gerrytan, I did what you suggested in caching and the same execution went from 2 minutes to 9 seconds! What I did was store the whole table in a hashmap since the table only consists of id and name. Thanks again!